# Not able to select a value from drop down & click in java Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, dropdown

driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/ng-dropdown-panel/div/div[2]/div[2]/span")).click();

It says no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/ng-dropdown-panel/div/div[2]/div[8]/span"}

Comment: Where is the HTML? How can we tell if the Xpath is correctwithout?

Comment: From whatever I can understand, you are trying to run Selenium on an Angular page and this won't work.